# Why do 'string-like' values that follow a number get ignored when printed?

Tags: c++, string

Here is a simple program that demonstrates this issue.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double d;

int main() {

    cin >> d;

    if (cin.fail()) {

        cout << "Input is invalid" << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << d << endl;

    }

    return (0);

}
```

Entering a value like `adsfasdf` or `!@#$!*@#(&Adf` prints `Input is invalid` as expected. Entering a numeric value like `13.52` returns `13.52`, also as expected.

But entering something that starts out as a number, but follows with strings, such as `13.52asdfasdf!#@$!@#$!#A` prints `13.52`. So why does that kind of input not print `Input is invalid`?

How do I get this input to be treated as invalid, instead of just printing the numeric part?

Comment: This is the way `cin` works, read the manual for details; it tries to read what you need at best and let remaining for future readings. It is not designed to be used as-is as an input validator. You may read the entire line as a string, and validate it by yourself.

Comment: As always, read in the data as a string and validate it from there.

Comment: What's the definition of _**input**_? Is it all contiguous characters (i.e., not space delimited)? If so, then then replace `double d; cin >> d;` with `std::string input; std::cin >> input;` and then parse to see if it's _**valid per your criteria**_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, when you try to read a value out of a stream, it will read as much as possible from the stream as long as it matches the expected format, leaving everything else untouched. If the read wasn't able to read any values at all, then it sets the fail bit on the stream. This explains why if you enter total garbage you get an error, whereas if you enter a number followed by garbage you'll read valid data, but still have garbage left in the stream.

One way to get around this is to use the `std::getline` function to read a line of text from `cin`, which will pick up everything the user typed in, and to then parse it by running it through a `std::istringstream`. Here's one way to do this, based on some code that we used to use at Stanford in our intro classes:

```
int readInt() {
    while (true) {
       std::string input;
       std::getline(cin, input); // Read a line of text from the user

       /* Set up an istringstream to read the data */
       std::istringstream converter(input);

       /* Try to read an int. If we succeed, make sure there wasn't
        * any trailing data.
        */
       int value;
       if (converter >> value) {
           char leftover;
           if (converter >> leftover) {
               std::cout << "Please enter an integer." << std::endl;
           } else {
               return value;
           }
       } else {
            std::cout << "Please enter an integer." << std::endl;
       }
    }
}
```

You can easily customize / templatize this to read data of whatever type seems most appropriate.